# Confusion about the number of solutions of a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

In the lectures, the rank of a matrix $A$ was defined to be the number of non-zero rows in the matrix obtained after reducing $A$ to row echelon form.

Then the lecturer stated that if $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(A\,|\,\mathbf{b})-1$, then the system of linear equations $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ has no solution.

I have now encountered an example where I think this statement is false. If my augmented matrix is

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&a&2\\
0&1&-(2a+1)&-3\\
0&0&-(a+2)&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then if I want to have no solution, I should have $a+2\not=0$ so that $a\not=-2$. Then my augmented matrix would reduce to

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&a&2\\
0&1&-(2a+1)&-3\\
0&0&1&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and since I have the contradiction $1=0$, I have no solution.

However the rank of $A$ is now $3$ and the rank of augmented matrix is also 3; so the condition $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(A\,|\,\mathbf{b})-1$ does not hold; therefore it should not be the case that I have no solution but clearly I got a contradiction.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no contradiction there, that only means that in the system of linear equations $$A\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}=\mathbf{b}$$ the third component, $x_3$, is $0$.

Comment: I see where I made a mistake. Thanks for the answer. I just took $0x_3=1$ wrongly with $1x_3=0$.